# Android: Difference between a System Resource and an Application Resource?

Tags: java, android, android-resources

From Android documentation for the `Resources` class:

```
public static Resources getSystem ()
```

> Added in API level 1 Return a global shared Resources object that
>   provides access to only system resources (no application resources),
>   and is not configured for the current screen (can not use dimension
>   units, does not change based on orientation, etc).

What are **system resources** and **application resources** and what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Application resources are**

1. Animation Resources (**R.anim**) --> res/anim
2. Color State List Resource(**R.color**) --> res/color
3. Drawable Resources (**R.drawable**) --> res/drawable
4. Layout Resource (**R.layout**) -- >res/layout

see this link for [more details](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html)

---

**System resources are**

1. Android ids (**android.R.id**)
2. Android's widgets (**android:id/tabs**)
3. Color (**android.R.color.transparent**)

see this post for [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631278/useful-android-system-resources)

Answer (score 3):

System Resources:

Android OS by default as has some resources which it uses in many places like `cancel` and `ok` strings. Event image resources like `close` icon and many more. One can use the directly in your application by getting that resource. As it's static, so can use it Absolutely everywhere

`Resources.getSystem().getString(android.R.string.cancel);//for system resources only`

- For System resources you use `android.R.`(anim, color, string, id, drawable)

Application Resources:

In your application you have many strings which you use it in many UI Components which is meant to change dynamically on the scenario basis for that purpose you're going to use your application resources. You need a `context` to get that application resources as it's not static one.

```
getApplicationContext().getResource().getString(R.string.cancel);//cancel string which you've define in values/strings.xml
```

- For application you use `R.`(anim,drawable,id,string,color)