# Resource Not Found Exception in class without context or activity

Tags: android

```
public class EmergencyNumbersGenerator {

    private static ArrayList<EmergencyNumberFeatures> features;

    public static ArrayList<EmergencyNumberFeatures> generateEmergencyNumber()
    {

        features = new ArrayList<>();

        EmergencyNumberFeatures em = new EmergencyNumberFeatures(
                Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.policeControl),
                Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.policeControlNumber)
        );
    }

}
```

This happens to be my code and this class EmergencyNumberGenerator has no Context whatsoever. So, I looked in SO for solution to get string from strings.xml and found that I can use

```
Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.{stringID})
```

But, I am getting error where it says, Resource is not found.

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0d0085
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:348)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:441)
    at com.utilnepal.MobileHelp.data.EmergencyNumbersGenerator.generateEmergencyNumber(EmergencyNumbersGenerator.java:20)
    at com.utilnepal.MobileHelp.ActivitiesFragment.EmergencyFragment.onCreateView(EmergencyFragment.java:43)
```

Any help regarding this issue?

Comment: Can you pass context in this class ?? and you can use it like that 
context.getResources().getString();

Comment: I could. But I preferred not to. I am looking for way around!

Comment: Use shared preferences instead

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass context in your static method. Only using context or Activity you can get String from your string file.

```
public static ArrayList<EmergencyNumberFeatures> generateEmergencyNumber(Context mContext)
{

    features = new ArrayList<>();

    EmergencyNumberFeatures em = new EmergencyNumberFeatures(
            mContext.getString(R.string.policeControl),
           mContext.getString(R.string.policeControlNumber)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, `Resources.getSystem()` you can use everywhere in yours code.

But with that you can get only System Resources. String, that you defined in strings.xml is not system resource.

Check this link [system resources and non-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021821/android-difference-between-a-system-resource-and-an-application-resource)